# Can I run a function when uploading a new picture to Instagram?

Tags: php, image, upload, instagram, instagram-api

Is there a way to launch a function on my server every time I upload a photo on Instragram via API?

I would like to create a page on my CMS automatically every time I upload a photo.

Comment: I don't really understand. Who uploads a photo via API? You or the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Real-time Photo Updates](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

Or you want publish photo via API ? If yes, it's not possible via official API.

Comment: Every time I publish a photo on my instagram account, would that automatically will create a post on my site.
The only solution I think is a control script of recent media and a cronjob.